Clustering for SBERT embedding
I have a set of sentences which I have transformed into vectors using SBERT embedding. I would like to cluster these vectors.
When looking for informations online, I keep seeing post telling to do some classical clustering, either using KMeans (which then use the Euclidean distance), or using (1-cosine) as the distance (eg nltk.cluster.cosine_distance() ) which is definitely not a distance.
I don't understand the validity of these methods: in the first case, the distance used is not a distance that is meaningful for similarity, and in the second case, it is not a distance.
Are these methods valid? If yes, why? And if not, what would be a good approach to cluster?

Once the sentences were transformed into vectors representing their semantic embedding, using KMeans is fine. The further two points in this vector space lay appart from each other, the lower is their semantic similarity and the lower their chance of going into the same cluster is. So this approach works, I did this previously in multiple projects and it always worked for me. It is even suggested in one of SentenceTransformers basic tutorials.
If run time is an issue because the number of sentences is extremely high, you can use something like faiss to speed up KMeans, as done in this notebook.

If Bert is thought using cosine similarity, then it is not the distance between 2 vectors that matters, but rather the angle between them. I can have for example 3 vectors a, b and c such that a and b are colinear, but such that d(a,b)> d(b,c). Your reasoning will tell that b and c have a closer semantic similarity than a and b, which is actually not the case.
I understand that this approach using the Euclidean distance kind of works in many cases (not all, I had issue with this, hence my post) and is way easier to implement. It is a nice approximation but it does not seem rigorous.

It could make sens though if the vectors are first normalized.

That is true, but in practice calculating all pairwise cosine distances and finding an optimal solution from all these pairwise cosine distances is computationally infeasible, so I never really saw anyone do that. In the documentation (https://sbert.net/docs/sentence_transformer/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html#similarity-calculation) they just suggest that you can use dot product instead of cosine in case of normalized vectors.

I guess if you really wanted to stick to cosine distance you could go with an approximation such as Locality Sensitive Hashing (https://ethen8181.github.io/machine-learning/recsys/content_based/lsh_text.html), which basically tries to group ( = give identical hash values to ) vectors that have similar angles into hash buckets and then finds similar elements by hashing an element and considering all elements in the same bucket a similarity candidate. But since this is again an approximation the question is if this actually would produce better results than the K-Means way of approximation.
